# How do I paint an image on the screen?

Tags: java, image

I want to add an image to the screen using the paint method? I do not want to use a JLabel because I want to set the location myself.

Board.class:

```
public class Board extends JPanel{
    BufferedImage image;

public Board() {
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\alexa_000\\Pictures\\RocketShip.png"));
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
}
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(image.getWidth(),image.getHeight());
}

}
```

RType.class:

```
public class RType extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                Panel panel = new Panel();
                frame.setContentPane(panel);
                frame.setSize(800,600);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Where do you override this `paint` method? In class which extends `JPanel`?

Comment: Please post a more complete program, one we can run and that shows us what is not working, an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Here is a good tutorial for you: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/painting/

Comment: Also please search this site since there are tons of examples of drawing with Java that are relevant to this question, some examples written by me even.

Comment: I added the rest of the program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have so many mistakes I don't know even where to start... Instead of displaying image on `JLabel` you can display your image on some container. Like `JPanel`. 
Here is a small demo which demonstrates how to display image on `JPanel`. Explanation in code.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

//No need to extend your class with JFrame
public class Board {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                //Instantiate Panel class.
                Panel panel = new Panel();
                //Set instance of Panel class as a content pane for your JFrame
                frame.setContentPane(panel);
                //Avoid calling setSize. Call pack instead
                frame.pack();
                //If you want to position your frame on center of screen, no need
                //for fancy calculations. This is how you can do it.
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

    /*Image will be displayed on JPanel*/
    private static class Panel extends JPanel {
        BufferedImage image;

        public Panel() {
            try {
                //String you are passing in "new File()" is a path to your image
                image = ImageIO.read(new File("path-to-your-image"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /*Override this method to display graphics on JPanel.
        * Do not override paint method!*/
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image,0,0,this);

        }

        /*Override getPreferredSize method so it returns dimensions of your image.
        * Size of your container (Panel) will be equal to size of that image*/
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(image.getWidth(),image.getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the way you started the question :p I'm relatively new to java so that is why there is a lot of mistakes. Anyway, I tried your answer and I could not get it to work. I updated the code I tried if you want to look at it again :D

Comment: @alexdr3437: this means that your path to your image file is probably wrong. It is better to use an InputStream though, but 1+ to this answer. Also, you really should go through the tutorial that is linked to in your comments. You can't guess at this stuff and hope that it might work.

Comment: Copy that code exactly what it looks like. Set your path as: `C:/Users/alexa_000/Pictures/RocketShip.png`. It should work. I just tested my code.

Comment: Alright it worked. The "\\"'s usually work, is there a reason why it didn't here? Thanks by the way.

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: Weird...I use it too and it worked when I passed path as you did.